# Ext.net How to check row GridPanel with CheckboxSelectionModel

Tags: c#, checkbox, ext.net, gridpanel

I have a GridView

```
  <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanelRoles" runat="server" StoreID="StoreUserTypes" ForceFit="true"
                            Title="">
                              <View>
                                <ext:GridView ID="GridViewRoles" runat="server" LoadMask="false" />
                            </View>
                             <SelectionModel>
                                <ext:CheckboxSelectionModel  ID="CheckboxSelectionModelMemTypes" runat="server" />
                            </SelectionModel>
                              <ColumnModel>
                                <Columns>
                                    <ext:Column ID="col_type_desc" runat="server" DataIndex="description" Text="" />
                                </Columns>
                                </ColumnModel>
    </ext:GridPanel>
```

and a store

```
 <ext:Store ID="StoreUserTypes" runat="server">
    <Reader>
        <ext:JsonReader IDProperty="id" />
    </Reader>
    <Model>
        <ext:Model ID="ModelUserTypes" runat="server" IDProperty="id">
            <Fields>
                <ext:ModelField Name="id" />
                <ext:ModelField Name="description" />
            </Fields>
        </ext:Model>
    </Model>
</ext:Store>
```

I want to check some rows after i i fill the grid (through c#) depending on their id (id is not appear on grid). I have tried

```
  CheckboxSelectionModel sm = GridPanelRoles.GetSelectionModel() as   CheckboxSelectionModel;

            sm.Select(id);
```

But this does not working.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    sm.SelectedRows.Add(new SelectedRow(id));
```

**Note:** Make sure that the variable `id` is of type **string**

Comment: I do not want to add rows. I just while binding some rows be checked in selection model.

Comment: @kostasch. this code doesn't add rows, it adds the existing row with the given id to the selected rows list, meaning the rows will be checked, did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.3 you need to add

```
GridPanelRoles.Render();
```

or

```
sm.UpdateSelection();
```